# How to Link Gravity forms to Odoo CRM

Tags: wordpress, odoo, crm, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am having a simple form built on gravity forms to gather leads from website. Now I am planning to use Odoo CRM to manage my leads. Is there any way to link the form with Odoo CRM?
The form is having only 3 fields: Name, Phone and Email.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily setup this integration with the help  [Gravity Forms CRM Addon](https://codecanyon.net/item/gravity-forms-crm-addon/10521695)

Comment: Rajat, this plugin not updated since last year. Do we really use this? Will it be compatible with the latest version of WordPress?